# How to change the fill color of an svg by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm completely new to web development and javascript, (but i have a basic understanding of programming)
i want to create a bunch of buttons that have different colors, and give the user the ability to click on a button to choose a color and then go fill a region (path) in a an svg image, my problem is that i create a variable that takes the value of the color when clicking on the button and i use it to color the path on the svg image and when ever i choose a different color from the buttons the color changes in the svg image without clicking on it. I want to be able to keep the previous color on the svg image until i click again on it to change. Please somebody help and sorry for the long message.
This is HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pathcolors3.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="swatches">
    <button style="background: rgb(153,153,0)"></button>
    <button style="background: rgb(103,103,0)"></button>
    <button style="background: rgb(100,100,0)"></button>
    <button style="background: rgb(10,20,100)"></button>
    <button style="background: rgb(26,75,100)"></button>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <svg>
 xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
 xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 viewBox="0 0 793.70667 1122.52"
 height="1122.52"
 width="793.70667"
 xml:space="preserve"
 id="svg2"
 version="1.1"><metadata
 id="metadata8"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
     rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
       rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
 id="defs6" /><g
 transform="matrix(1.3333333,0,0,-1.3333333,0,1122.52)"
 id="g10"><path class="zone1"
 id="path12" 
   fill="";stroke:#1d1d1b;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke- 
 miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
   d="M 584.447,109.821 H 17.518 V 676.75 h 566.929 z" /><path class="zone2"
   id="path14"
   fill="";stroke:#1d1d1b;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke- 
miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
   d="M 242.566,109.741 H 129.18 V 676.67 h 113.386 z" /><path class="zone3"
   id="path16"
   fill="";stroke:#1d1d1b;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke- 
 miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
   d="M 471.022,109.894 H 357.636 v 566.929 h 113.386 z" /></g></svg>



<script src="main3.js">
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

This is CSS

```
:root{
    --Lawn: rgb(100,100,100); /* this is the variable */
  }

  path {
 fill: grey;
 cursor: pointer;
 stroke: black;
 stroke-width: 1px;
 stroke-linejoin: round;;
 }


 .selected1{
 fill: var(--Lawn);
 }

 .selected2{
  fill: var(--Lawn);
 }

 .selected3{
 fill: var(--Lawn);
}



.swatches button{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100px;
 height:100px; 
 cursor: pointer;
 }
```

and this is javascript

```
 $('#path12').on("click", function() {
 $('#path12.selected1').attr("class", "");
 $(this).attr("class", "selected1");
 });

 $('#path14').on("click", function() {
 $('#path14.selected2').attr("class", "");
 $(this).attr("class", "selected2");
 });

$('#path16').on("click", function() {
$('#path16.selected3').attr("class", "");
$(this).attr("class", "selected3");
});

    var root=document.querySelector(':root');
    var swatches = document.querySelectorAll('.swatches button');

    
    swatches.forEach((swatch)=>{
        swatch.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
            root.style.setProperty('--Lawn',e.target.style.background);
            
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three classes `selected1`, `selected2` and `selected3` are all set to the same thing:

```
fill: var(--Lawn);
```

So if you update that CSS variable, all three classes will change.  `var(--Lawn)` is a reference to the `--Lawn` variable.  It's not a copy of the value.

So using CSS variables is the wrong approach.  Use a JS variable instead.

Another problem is that your SVG is broken. There is a problem with the attributes in your `<path>` element.  Did you edit the file manually?

```
 <svg>
 xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"

..snip..

<path class="zone1"
 id="path12" 
   fill="";stroke:#1d1d1b;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke- 
 miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
```

should be something like:

```
 <svg
 xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"

..snip..

<path class="zone1"
 id="path12"
   fill="none" 
   style="stroke:#1d1d1b;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
```

Anyway, here's an example of how I might do it.

```js
// Holds the currently selected colour
// Initialised to the background colour of the button we have marked as id="defaultColour"
var  selectedColour = $("#defaultColour").css("backgroundColor");

// Click handler for buttons
$('.swatches button').on("click", function(event) {
  // Set selectedColour to the background colour of the button that the user clicked on
  selectedColour = $(event.target).css("backgroundColor");
});

// Click handler for SVG paths
$('#svg2 path').on("click", function(event) {
  // Set the path's fill colour to the currently selected colur
  $(event.target).css("fill", selectedColour);
});
```

```css
path {
  fill: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;;
}

.swatches button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px; 
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swatches">
    <button style="background: rgb(153,153,0)" id="defaultColour"></button>
    <button style="background: rgb(103,103,0)"></button>
    <button style="background: rgb(100,100,0)"></button>
    <button style="background: rgb(10,20,100)"></button>
    <button style="background: rgb(26,75,100)"></button>
</div>

<svg
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 viewBox="0 0 793.70667 1122.52"
 height="1122.52"
 width="793.70667"
 xml:space="preserve"
 id="svg2">
 
 <g transform="matrix(1.3333333,0,0,-1.3333333,0,1122.52)" id="g10">
   <path class="zone1"
 id="path12"
     fill="none"
     style="stroke:#1d1d1b;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="M 584.447,109.821 H 17.518 V 676.75 h 566.929 z" />
   <path class="zone2"
     id="path14"
     fill="none"
     style="stroke:#1d1d1b;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="M 242.566,109.741 H 129.18 V 676.67 h 113.386 z" />
   <path class="zone3"
     id="path16"
     fill="none"
     style="stroke:#1d1d1b;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="M 471.022,109.894 H 357.636 v 566.929 h 113.386 z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks so much man !, it works perfectly.